# Strip everything after the last sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
var text = 'Hello. World... Lorem? Ipsum 123';
```

Using javascript regex, how can I strip everything that is after the **last** `.`, `?`, `!` (the end of the *last* sentence).

With the above example, it should result to:

```
text = 'Hello. World... Lorem?';
```

Comment: Try: `text = text.replace(/^(.*[?!.]).*/, "$1")`

Comment: `string.replace(/[^.?!]+$/,'')`.

Comment: Please note that users like to use "Needs focus" when they think a Question needs effort. I'm really sorry about this.

Comment: What should be done when no  `.`, `?`, or `!` exists in the input? What you want done in that case substantially affects what code to write.

Comment: What should happen with line breaks? If there's an `.!?` on the first line, but none in the second line, should the second line be removed too? Or is the second line to be analysed separately? Meaning should the regex consume line breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a regex replacement:

```js
var text = 'Hello. World... Lorem? Ipsum 123';
var output = text.replace(/([.?!])(?!.*[.?!]).*$/, "$1");
console.log(output);
```

The replacement logic here says to:

```
([.?!])      match and capture a closing punctuation
(?!.*[.?!])  then assert that this punctuation in fact
             be the final one
.*           match and consume all remaining text
$            until the end of the input
```

Then we replace that final punctuation mark.  We could, in theory, have used a lookbehind, but this isn't supported on all versions of JavaScript (not at least on SO's demo tool).

Comment: Using a negative look-ahead here is a bit inefficient (the last portion of the text is scanned twice) and unnecessarily complex. Just use `/([.?!])[^.?!]*$/`. You could use the even shorter `/[^.?!]*$/`, but that would be even worse from an efficiency POV, as it would try to scan to the end of the input from every character. It also makes different assumptions as to what to do when there's no `[.?!]` character and about `\n`, `\r`, `\u2028` or `\u2029` characters. What should be used depends on what the OP wants done when there are no `[.?!]` characters and about line terminators.

Comment: I've deleted and undeleted the question a couple of times, checking to see if and why the "acceptance" mark becomes invisible when the question is deleted. Each time it's deleted, you lose the +15 from acceptance and the +10 from the upvote, but you regain the -2 from the downvote. When the Q&A is undeleted, the reverse happens. So that's why your rep history is lighting up like a Christmas tree. Sorry, and happy holidays! :-)

Comment: Hi Cody `:-)` ... so it's basically just the usual delayed rep phenomenon.  Cheers!